# setcookie command not working

Tags: php, netbeans

I use this command to set a cookie in my project

```
setcookie("userstate",$loginusername);
```

but it does not run 
I also use

```
echo setcookie("userstate",$loginusername);
```

but it dose not work too

I use netbeans and this command is recognized in it but it is not work
what is the solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Doesn't the cookie get set? You can't `echo` a boolean value. Use `var_dump()` to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You set a cookie using `setcookie("cookie_name", $value);`, so you've got that right. You access a cookie, using the superglobal variable `$_COOKIE`. It's an associative array, and you can use it like this:

```
setcookie("userstate", $loginusername);
echo $_COOKIE["userstate"];
```